# LINQ query is not working

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list. I am trying to filter the list such that it contains the id that I am adding as a key to the dictionary. So dictionary would be Key, List - with id as Key.
I have no idea why the following won't work - although the rawlist contains ids, filteredlist is empty. I am checking the value within the loop. Fresh set of eyes please?
resultList is dictionary(string, List)

```
    For Each c As String In listIds
    Dim filteredlist = rawList.Where(Function(x) x.id.Trim().Contains(c.Trim())).ToList()
    resultList.Add(c,filteredlist)
    Next
```

I need the filtered list. I have tried Contains, Equals and "=" 
i.e.

```
    Dim filteredlist = rawList.Where(Function(x) x.id.Trim().Equals(c.Trim())).ToList()
```

and

```
    Dim filteredlist = rawList.Where(Function(x) x.id.Trim() = (c.Trim())).ToList()
```

Please look into it thanks!

Comment: *"I need the filtered list."* No doubt. In what sense does the code "not work"? The rawlist contains IDs, and is at the same time empty? Can you describe what you *want* to see, and what you see instead?

Comment: Sorry. I although the rawlist contains items with id = c, the filtered list is empty.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `filteredList` once you've applied the filter. You'll need to provide more details on what the inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs are if you want more insightful help.

Comment: any particular reason you are asking if `id` contains `c` if you are actually wanting when `id` equals `c`?

Comment: Where are you looking at `filteredList`? Inside the loop or outside?

Comment: @ Ed - The dictionary is empty hence I was looking at the list value inside the loop.
@ David - I am filtering the list such that it contains the items matching id. 
@ Andy - couldn't I just check if the list contains the values or not? Before doing any action

Comment: `resultList` must be the dictionary, judging from the name? And you're adding `rawtlist` to it. Is that a typo for `rawList`? Wait, did you say the dictionary is *empty*? No items in it? `resultList.Count == 0`? Or it contains empty lists?

Comment: @Ed yes sorry I have modified. Both the resultlist and filteredlist are empty. :(

Comment: If there are no items in `resultList`, then it is very difficult for me to imagine how there could be any items in `listIds`. Is the loop body executing at all?

Comment: yes loop is executing

Comment: So you're adding items to `resultList` but there are no items in it. Or are you showing us completely different code than you're running?

Comment: Does `listIds` have the exact matches that you want or partial matches?

Comment: If you use `listIds = New List(Of String) From {rawData(0).Id}` before the loop, so that you are guaranteed to have something to return, does it work?

Comment: You said "resultList is dictionary(string, List)" - but what are the elements of that List meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have it backwards.  Typically you have a list for looking for something first and not iterate through that list which IMHO takes longer.

[Filter Linq Child Collection by another List/Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665597/filter-linq-child-collection-by-another-list-array/39665878#39665878)

```
Public Class POC
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Desc As String
    Public Property Orders As List(Of Order)
End Class

Public Class Order
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Desc As String
End Class

Private Shared Function GetOrders(numberOfOrders As Integer) As List(Of Order)
    Dim orders = New List(Of Order)()

    For i As Integer = 1 To numberOfOrders
        orders.Add(New Order() With { .Id = i, .Desc = "{i} Order" })
    Next

    Return orders
End Function

Private Shared Function GetPOCOsAndOrders() As List(Of POC)
    Return New List(Of POC)() From { _
        New POC() With { .Id = 1, .Desc = "John", .Orders = GetOrders(1) }, 
        New POC() With { .Id = 2, .Desc = "Jane", .Orders = GetOrders(2) },
        New POC() With { .Id = 3, .Desc = "Joey", .Orders = GetOrders(3) }
End Function


Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim orders = New List(Of Integer)() From { 2, 3 }
    Dim items = GetPOCOsAndOrders()

    Dim peopleAndOrdersWhereOrderNumberIsGreaterThanTwo = items.Where(Function(x) x.Orders.Any(Function(y) orders.Contains(y.Id)))

    'I should only get the last two people out of three and their orders
    peopleAndOrdersWhereOrderNumberIsGreaterThanTwo.ToList().ForEach(Function(x) Console.WriteLine("{x.Id} {x.Desc} {x.Orders.Count}"))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many silght variations possible with the limited information you have given us, but a working example is:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Public Class datum
        Property Id As String
        Property Name As String

        Public Sub New()
            ' empty constructor
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(Id As String, Name As String)
            Me.Id = Id
            Me.Name = Name
        End Sub

    End Class

    Sub Main()
        ' sample data...
        Dim rawData = New List(Of datum)
        rawData.Add(New datum("cat", "Lulu"))
        rawData.Add(New datum("cat", "Uschi"))
        rawData.Add(New datum("snake", "Sid"))
        rawData.Add(New datum("fox", "Reynard"))
        rawData.Add(New datum("mouse", "Jerry"))

        ' what to look for:
        Dim listIds As New List(Of String) From {"CAT", "mouse", "ELK"}

        ' somewhere to store the results:
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

        ' filter by what to look for:
        For Each c In listIds
            Dim foundItems = rawData.Where(Function(x) String.Compare(x.Id, c, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0)

            ' only add items to the dictionary if the Id was found:
            If foundItems.Count() > 0 Then
                ' use the case of the id from the raw data:
                dict.Add(foundItems(0).Id, foundItems.Select(Function(f) f.Name).ToList())
            End If

            ' alternative which includes dictionary entries where the Id was not found:
            'dict.Add(If(foundItems.Count = 0, c, foundItems(0).Id), foundItems.Select(Function(f) f.Name).ToList())

        Next

        ' show the dictionary contents:
        For Each kvp In dict
            Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key & ": " & String.Join(", ", kvp.Value))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Output:

> cat: Lulu, Uschi
>   mouse: Jerry

I have included commented-out code for some variations you may want.